# failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Tags: php, caching

I have uploaded my localhost files to my website but it is showing me this error:-

```
: [2] file_put_contents( ***WebsiteURL*** /cache/lang/ ***FileName*** .php) 
[function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does 
not support writeable connections | LINE: 127 | FILE: /home/content/
***Folders\FileName*** .php
```

What i personally feel that the contents get saved in a file in cache folder and when i uploaded the files to my web server it is trying to access the cached localhost folder.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Instead of doing `file_put_contents(***WebSiteURL***...)` you need to use the server path to `/cache/lang/file.php` (e.g. `/home/content/site/folders/filename.php`).

You cannot open a file over `HTTP` and expect it to be written.  Instead you need to open it using the local path.

Comment: I am using amazon webservices s3 storage area. I don't have the server path but just the URL. **How to get the path?**

Comment: @BannedfromSO I'm not too familiar with s3 storage area but I'm guessing you can't use file_put_contents and need to use their API or http put instead.

Comment: The fact is I could able to upload the image but it's showing 0 bytes after upload completed. Yes, I am using AWS PHP SDK kit.

Comment: @BannedfromSO Might wanna create a new question then, I'm not sure how related to this post it is.

Comment: While I tried to post a new question more or less, tangible situation faced by other programmers, but those solution doesn't suites my issue. Just thinking that people may set flag to close the question and may downvote. so didn't post.

Comment: Well file_put_contents only works on the same server it is called from, so you can't use file_put_contents to write from one server to another.

Comment: @Neocortex I know this is old, but for future reference or other readers it is possible to use file_put_contents for files on S3 if you use the S3 StreamWrapper in the PHP AWS SDK. https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/TxKV69TBGSONBU/Amazon-S3-PHP-Stream-Wrapper

Answer (score 19):

you could use fopen() function.

some example:

```
$url = 'http://doman.com/path/to/file.mp4';
$destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/downloads/';


    $newfname = $destination_folder .'myfile.mp4'; //set your file ext

    $file = fopen ($url, "rb");

    if ($file) {
      $newf = fopen ($newfname, "a"); // to overwrite existing file

      if ($newf)
      while(!feof($file)) {
        fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );

      }
    }

    if ($file) {
      fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
      fclose($newf);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried a lot of solutions but this is the only that worked for me.

Comment: No problem :D :D

Answer (score 3):

it is because of using web address, You can not use http to write data. don't use :
http:// or https:// in your location for upload files or save data or somting like that. instead of of using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] use $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].
for example :

wrong :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["File"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"].'/uploads/images/1.jpg')
```

correct:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["File"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/uploads/images/1.jpg')
```

Comment: Dan awesome stuff my mate

Answer (score 2):

> May this code help you. It works in my case.

```
$filename = "D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/uploads/json/2018-10-25.json";
    $fileUrl = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/json/2018-10-25.json";
    if(!file_exists($filename)):
        $handle = fopen( $filename, 'a' ) or die( 'Cannot open file:  ' . $fileUrl ); //implicitly creates file
        fwrite( $handle, json_encode(array()));
        fclose( $handle );
    endif;
    $response = file_get_contents($filename);
    $tempArray = json_decode($response);
    if(!empty($tempArray)):
        $count = count($tempArray) + 1;
    else:
        $count = 1;
    endif;
    $tempArray[] = array_merge(array("sn." => $count), $data);
    $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
    file_put_contents($filename, $jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the url path like:
use this:
"assets/admin/uploads/images/file.jpg"

not this:
http://localhost:10965/assets/admin/uploads/images/drawing/drawing1694111655.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).