# Getting Error on fopen in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple text editor for a template, and I've gotten the opening, displaying, and editing part handled. Every time I try to save it though, it keeps giving me an error on the fopen() function.

I'm getting the files with this:

```
$dir = "./uploads/post-templates";
$files = scandir($dir);
while($files[0] == "." || $files[0] == "..") {
    array_shift($files);
}
```

Then a simple loop handles displaying filenames in a select menu:

```
<?php foreach($files as $f) {   echo "<option name='file' value=" . $f . " class='file'>" . $f . "</option>";}; ?>
```

Lastly it is all appended into the textarea using a short jQuery function. Alas, when it comes to executing the script to save the file, I get an error every single time. I've tried using relatives, absolutes, and http for the directory, and the filename and path are echoing properly each time.

```
///different file!!!!
$f = $_POST['file'];
$c = $_POST['content'];
$dir = "./uploads/post-templates/";
$file = $dir . $f;
echo $file;
$fo = fopen($file, "w") or die("opening error");
fwrite($fo, $c) or die("writing error");
fclose($f);
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what error you are getting exactly?

Comment: none specifically, it's triggering my or die()

Comment: Is all you're doing getting the names for a list of files in a `SELECT`? Why use `fopen()` for that? I would use a table (personally), but you could `glob('/path/to/directory/*.tmpl')` and go through an array of file names.

Comment: Have you checked your permissions?

Comment: yup, chmodded to 777 for testing

Comment: `$fo` is the var set to the filehandler for `fopen`

Comment: Also, I think you could `try catch` and print the `Exception $e` and that might be more descriptive. Using `die` or `exit` like this as error-handling is often more of a problem than a solution.

Comment: This seems questionable to me `;};` but I could be wrong, anyone can correct me on this, of course.

Comment: Oops, extra semicolon. `try catch` with the echo didn't yield anything

Comment: Are you using an actual file upload (as opposed to two fields you save to a file)? If so, you have to look in `$_FILES` and use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead. If not, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to inspect what those variables are before `fopen()` is run.

Comment: No, I'm just using a save form... the apache2 log is saying "failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in <directory>"

Comment: @mike Have you tried `$dir = "uploads/post-templates/";` without the `./`? Since I take it you're executing from your root?

Comment: @mike Try this `$file = $dir . "/" . $f;` - Made up a test file and when I did not include the concatenated `/` did not create a seperation between folder and file.

Comment: I think the path issue @Fred points out is probably a big part of the problem. You need to print out those values that `fopen` sees so you can make sure it makes sense.

Comment: Well I've managed to get rid of the open error. I've been echoing the path-to-file the entire time. So no error now, but it's not saving

Comment: You should search for your `HTTP wrapper` error (the full line). [Maybe this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748076/failed-to-open-stream-http-wrapper-does-not-support-writeable-connections)

Comment: @mike I wrote a quick script with successful results. I will post as answer for you to see it.

Answer (score 0):

### NOTE: For testing purposes only.

I wrote a test script and it was successful.

With the values that you have Mike, try using my script below with your present incoming values.

Plus this line gave me an error from your original code: `fclose($f);`

**Error**: when using `fclose($f);`

> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in...

It should read as `fclose($fo);`

### TEST CODE:

```
<?php

$f = "thefile.txt";
$c = "the content";
$dir = "./test/";
$file = $dir . "/" . $f;
echo $file; // echos the file name at this point
$fo = fopen($file, "w") or die("opening error");
fwrite($fo, $c) or die("writing error");
fclose($fo);

// shows the contents of the written file on screen
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

echo $contents;

?>
```