# use file_put_contents for download image

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like use `file_put_contents` to download and create many types (different sizes) of images from an URL (Facebook and Twitter).

My script looks like this:

```
$image = $user->getAvatarSocial(); 
//image like: => https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4.png
file_put_contents($image, file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

But I receive this error:

> Warning:
>   fopen(http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4.png):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections

I'm using Symfony 2.3.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748076/failed-to-open-stream-http-wrapper-does-not-support-writeable-connections)

Comment: @Thibault the image is not in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't try to put contents into a distant image file.

[file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) takes 2 arguments :

- the first one is the local path
- the second is the content

Here you are giving a HTTP path to write the file. Your PHP script can't write into Twitter web server.

To do this you will have to use Twitter API or something.

What is in your `php://input` ?

Comment: `$image = $user->getAvatarSocial(); 
file_put_contents('foo.jpg', file_get_contents($image));`