# PHP - file_put_contents not working on server

Tags: php

I am trying to update an XML file on our server with the following code:-

```
$dom = $jobsXML->asXML();

file_put_contents("http://www.address.com/scripts/xml/jobs.xml", $dom) or print_r(error_get_last());;
```

and I get the following error message:-

```
[type] => 2
[message] => file_put_contents(http://www.address.com/scripts/xml/jobs.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
[file] => /var/www/vhosts/address.com/httpdocs/scripts/php/jobs.controller.php
[line] => 78
```

The file is set to chmod 777 so it is writable, also file_put_contents functions are enabled on the server.

Why else could this file not be writing?

Comment: I think the issue is due to using *HTTP* and the path won't match; if the FTP port is open try to use *FTP*

Comment: `file_put_contents` will **NOT** do an http upload for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a path, not a a domain url.

Eg:

```
$dom = $jobsXML->asXML();

file_put_contents("scripts/xml/jobs.xml", $dom) or print_r(error_get_last());
```

Source: [failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748076/failed-to-open-stream-http-wrapper-does-not-support-writeable-connections)

Comment: Thanks, working now! :) just to add you can find the path using <? echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?> if anyone is unsure

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

Try specifiying a path on your file system.

eg. file_put_contents('myfile.data'. $data);