# wordpress copy plugin uploaded file to theme dir

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a line of code that is supposed to copy image from one directory to another:

```
copy("http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/uploaded_background.jpg","http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/landing-page/img/desktop-background.jpg");
```

This is located in wordpress theme header.php file, however I am receiving an error message:

> Warning:
>   copy(http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/landing-page/img/desktop-background.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections in
>   C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\landing-page\header.php on
>   line 42

Line 42 is where my copy function line is located.

How can I solve this issue. Any suggestions or links would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using

```
 copy("http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/uploaded_background.jpg","http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/landing-page/img/desktop-background.jpg");
```

try

```
copy`("/yourserverfolderpath/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/uploaded_background.jpg","/yourserverfolderpath//wordpress/wp-content/themes/landing-page/img/desktop-background.jpg");`
```

`yourserverfolderpath/` could be something like `/home/user/abc/`

see you ftp or cpanel for exact path

see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748076/failed-to-open-stream-http-wrapper-does-not-support-writeable-connections) as guideline

**PS:**
In case of local file, path would be something like `D:\php\www\www\xml.php`

as pointed by @dlegall in comments and as per documentation, First param of `copy()` can be a valid URL, see the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: Where should I check for this path if I am using it locally on wamp? Or you mean like actual path on C diska and so on?

Comment: Yes, in that case, it will be complete path, starting from your drive and ending at you file

Comment: @MindaugasJačionis does my answer helps you solve your issue? if yes, please accept it, otherwise, let someone else try to answer this question...

Comment: Just a note to say that the first parameter of copy() can be a remote url.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a local path as a 2nd parameter to copy(), since http protocol does not support file overwriting.

> The destination path. If dest is a URL, the copy operation may fail if the wrapper does not support overwriting of existing files. 
>   Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php