# Faster way to read RSS through Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, rss

Got another fun one for you all today.

I have working code that pulls from various RSS feeds and orders them by which of them has most recent pubdate.

The issues I have is that it is slow. It slows down the loading of the site. Not only that, because it's all hosted server side, it slows down the response if multiple people are accessing the site simultaneously.

So, I'd like to convert this into either a JavaScript function, which would then fill the  tag's innerHTML to what's pulled back from the database or another option that I would love for anyone to suggest (If it's faster).

Without further adieu: The Code:

**PHP**

```
function RSSFeeder() {
    $client = buildCon();
    //Query removed, simply gets the RSS URL from the database
    $query = "";
    $result = $client ->run($query);
    $RSSList = array();
    foreach($result ->getRecords() as $record)
    {
        $ComicArray = array();
        $ComicName = $record ->value('Name');
        $RSS = $record ->value('RSS');
        $URL = $record ->value('URL');
        $content = file_get_contents($RSS);
        $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
            $profile = $x ->channel ->item[$i];
            $pubDate = $profile ->{ "pubDate"};
        }
        $ComicArray['URL'] = $URL;
        $ComicArray['Comic'] = $ComicName;
        $ComicArray['pubDate'] = $pubDate;
        $RSSList[] = $ComicArray;
    }

    #usort($RSSList, "sortFunction");
    usort($RSSList, "compareRSSTimes");

    return $RSSList;
}
```

At the end, you probably saw the usort method, so here it is:

```
function compareRSSTimes($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a['pubDate']);
    $b = strtotime($b['pubDate']);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

From there, the array is sent back to a PHP script that builds the output based on the chronological order of updates.  It works fine. It just takes a little while to load the page and I'm worried about the sustainability of my terribad server if/when more users access the page.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is it doing this for every time a user hits that page?

Comment: @Randall Yes. And that is what is the problem. I would take suggestions on ways to fix this. (Note, I cannot set up timed triggers in the database I am using, they are not supported)

Comment: Have a script which runs on the server and polls the urls periodically. Parse the results and save them to your database in a format you can work with. Serve your content from your database instead of running this query every time. If you cant set up a cron job you coulld trigger the script to run by calling a certain url etc and insert a small pece of javascript into your page so it gets triggered when people visit your site, but without affecting their page load

Comment: @miknik That sounds like an excellent idea. I'm not too versed in running cron'd scripts server side, but I will definitely look into that as a more long-term solution! If there are any suggested readings or links you could point me at to get started, that would be super helpful!

Comment: If you have command line access to the server then setting up a cron job is super simple. Type `crontab -e` to see your current cron and adding a new job is just a single line of code like this `0 0 * * * php /path/to/script.php 2> /dev/null` The numbers and `*` specify when it runs, have a look at [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) for a syntax generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get away with doing this every so often, instead of every single time. If not able to use a database, using an oldschool method of just wrapping the 'heavy bits' in a cache file storage can work very quickly.

An example of that:

```
function RSSFeeder() {
    $cachefile = '/path/to/RSSList.json';// <- must be local server path, not a URL
    if (filemtime($cachefile) < strtotime('now -1 minute')) {
        // if stale, rebuild it

        // .. do your normal building of the $RSSList here ..

        file_put_contents($cachefile,json_encode($RSSList));
        return $RSSList;
    } else {
        // else output cache
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($cachefile),true);
    }
}
```

It could be more elegant... or use a bloated over the top fully featured library to do the same thing.

But this works, is self mending, only updates when called for, doesn't require a cron job, and is a weee bit faster than opening a db connection, querying the db, and outputting the data stored... but not huge enough. So your preference is more important there.

Comment: @Ranall This would be perfect (Though I'd probably put it to a shelf life of 30 minutes to an hour, but when I tried to implement it... the following:  failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: Huh, were you putting in the full URL path, instead of local path to where you wanted the file? (also you need to make a file first for it to use) IE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748076/failed-to-open-stream-http-wrapper-does-not-support-writeable-connections

Comment: Got the file up. Figured the problem. Can't use HTTP string, changed to local file. Works like a charm!

Comment: Yay! Now, thats only one way you can do this. miknik hinted at using a database table for the cache as well, and also using timed events (like crons, or external js timers). Various ways.